# how can I set a cookie with curl and windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, curl, cookies

I can log in with

curl -user username:password https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/auth/login/
When i afterwards try to get some projects with

curl https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/api/v2/get_projects
i have no authentification.

How can i set a cookie?

I tried

curl -user username:password --cookie-jar cookie.txt https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/auth/login
but get the error: Invoke-WebRequest : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "cookie.txt" akzeptiert. In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1 curl -user ... --cookie-jar c ...

thanks

Comment: The linked duplicate talks about `Invoke-RestMethod`, but the approach is exactly the same with `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: ok, I can set a cookie with $session = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]::new()
$cookie = [System.Net.Cookie]::new('cookieName', 'value')
$session.Cookies.Add('https://domain.tld/', $cookie) but how can I now set the username and password to the cookie?

Comment: Usually (depending on authn mechanism) you'd do an initial request with the credentials encoded in the `Authorization` header and the web server will set a cookie with a session cookie. To intercept the cookie set by the server, use `Invoke-WebRequest -SessionVariable mySessionVar`, and then pass `$mySessionVar` on subsequent requests, eg. `Invoke-WebRequest -WebSession $mySessionVar`

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I tried so:  curl -user  username:password https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/auth/login  -SessionVariable mySessionVar

and then 
curl -WebSession $mySessionVar https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/api/v2/get_projects .
But I get the error: curl : {"error":"Authentication failed: invalid or missing user\/password or session cookie."}
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ curl -WebSession $mySessionVar https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/i ..

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` is _not_ `curl`, it doesn't have quite the same parameter names. You'll want to create the credential with `Invoke-WebRequest -Credential ([pscredential]::new("username", $("password" |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)))`

Comment: sry, I understand nothing :(. I'm absolut new to this topic.
I tried:
Invoke-WebRequest -SessionVariable 'mySessionVar' -user  username:password -Uri https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/auth/login 
That was ok.
But
Invoke-WebRequest -WebSession $mySessionVar  "https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/api/v2/get_projects"  

was -> authorization failed